# Higher-Order Programming Using Boost::Python

Tags: python, boost, functional-programming, boost-python, higher-order-functions

So, I have a simple event library, written in C++ and using the Boost libraries. I wanted to expose said library to Python, so naturally I turned to Boost::Python. I got the code to compile, eventually, but now I'm faced with quite the problem: my library uses higher-order programming techniques. For example, the library is made up of three main classes: an event class, an event manager class, and an event listener class. The event listener class poses a problem. Code:

```
    class listener{
        public:
            listener(){}
            void alert(cham::event::event e){
                if (responses[e.getName()])
                    responses[e.getName()](e.getData());
            }
            void setResponse(std::string n, boost::function<void (std::string d)> c){responses.insert(make_pair(n, c));}
            void setManager(_manager<listener> *m){manager = m;}
        private:
            std::map<std::string, boost::function<void (std::string d)> > responses;
            _manager<listener> *manager;
```

As you can see, the function `setResponse` is the problem. It requires a function to be passed to it, and, unfortunately, Boost::Python does not apply it's converter magic in this situation. When called like the following:

```
>>> import chameleon
>>> man = chameleon.manager()
>>> lis = chameleon.listener()
>>> def oup(s):
...  print s
... 
>>> lis.setResponse("event", oup)
```

it gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
Boost.Python.ArgumentError: Python argument types in
    listener.setResponse(listener, str, function)
did not match C++ signature:
    setResponse(cham::event::listener {lvalue}, std::string, boost::function<void ()(std::string)>)
```

So, my question is, how could I fix this? It would have to either use overloading or a wrapper, as I would like the library to remain callable by C++.

Comment: +1 because I think Boost::Python is a very cool idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a wrapper around `setResponse`, which takes a `boost::python::object` instead of a function. It should store this `bp::object` in a known location (probably a member variable of a `listener` subclass).

Then pass a different c++ function to the base `setResponse`, that will know how to lookup and call the function in the `bp::object`. If events are to be called on a different thread, you will also need to ensure proper handling of python's Global Interpreter Lock, as discussed here: [boost.python not supporting parallelism?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009613/boost-python-not-supporting-parallelism).

Comment: Thanks! I fixed it before I read this, using pretty much the same methodology. I just added an additional template argument to listener, passed in python::object instead of boost::function, and named it python_listener with a typedef. Works like a charm.