# Running two python scripts parallel with boost::python

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, boost-python, cpython

I'm having a problem with my (game) application, which is using Boost.Python, when it comes to the scripting part. I have a client thread and a server thread that runs in the same process if you do not connect to an external server.

This is where my problems arise: It seems like the Python interpreter can't execute scripts in the client thread parallel with scripts in the server thread, as it causes the application to crash.

So my question is: Is there any possibility to run two (or more) scripts parallel in the Python interpreter?
I have been searching all day and found a lot of information regarding Py_NewInterpreter, but this does not solve my problem as it uses GIL, I don't want the interpreter to lock other scripts from executing as it will cause lag on the client and/or the server side.

Answer (score 1):

As of today, you cannot avoid `GIL` interactions when using python threads in the same process.

You may want to have a look at `multiprocessing` module which is meant to easily spawn Python processes, thus not interacting with `GIL`.

Another option is to explicitly release the `GIL` when its not needed in your wrapped C/C++ functions. This can be done using `PyEval_SaveThread` and `PyEval_RestoreThread` functions.

Comment: Full details about GIL Tiwtiling here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009613/boost-python-not-supporting-parallelism/8011153#8011153